# What problems should i expect with trying to dual boot Ubuntu on an Asus Laptop X54H with Windows 7?

Tags: laptop, dual-boot, asus

I got the following computer over Christmas,

Asus  Laptop / Intel® Pentium® Processor / 15.6" Display / 4GB Memory
Model: X54H-BD3MA
SKU: 4005394

I'm in the process of dual booting Ubuntu on it, but would appreciate some sort of idea on what to expect or what to look forward to. what makes Ubuntu more 'for beginners' than other distros or what proliferates that myth?

EDIT: 10 key is not working. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have many problems with the opensource driver; if you have, such as overheating, you can take a look at [this guide](http://cisight.com/solve-overheat-in-ubuntu-11-10-with-jupiter-vga-solution/) here to solve them.